# Can we have two PHP projects hosted using httpdocs for public folder of both the projects?

Tags: php, firebase-realtime-database, plesk

I have two PHP projects and I need to host both on Plesk, using the metthod "Sancho Almeda" provided a very good solution on : [How to deploy laravel project on the godaddy hosting server (Plesk Onyx CPanel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62826905/how-to-deploy-laravel-project-on-the-godaddy-hosting-server-plesk-onyx-cpanel). This article really helped me But does this work for two PHP projects at the same time ?

I mean, just wondering how could I have two two public folders for 2 different PHP projects in the httpdocs folder on Plesk (Windows shared hosting).

Answer (score 0):

The “document root” will be served as the `/` URL.  Under that, typically the web server looks for an `index.php` (assuming PHP) and serves it.

You can host as many discrete PHP applications as you want, although their `index.php` filenames will need to be distinguishable.

Creating two subdirectories under the document root (with a PHP application in each) will allow people to specify which `index.php` they wish to invoke - but the URLs will have to include the subdirectory name (`/applicationA/` vs `/applicationB/`).

The modifications to the `setup.php` or `index.php` as described in the other post you mention will need to also be distinguishable from each other.